# How to extract array values with numeric keys only?

Tags: php, arrays, extract

Considering array like:

```
$arr = array(
  'key' => 'foo'
  'key2' => 'bar',
   0 => 'num_foo',
   1 => 'num_bar'

);
```

How to extract values under 0 & 1? (Besides using for loop). Maybe any standard function do the job?

Comment: foreach loop `is_int`, `is_numeric` ...

Comment: Yeah, so beat me :) I just prefer inliner if I can instead of loop

Comment: Why can't you do it with a loop? Is this a school assignment?

Comment: any function, internal or user written, that iterates through an array will use a "loop". Do you even know why you don't want a loop?

Comment: If you’re using at least PHP 5.6, you can use `array_filter`, with the flag that tells it to pass the key to the callback function.

Comment: I don't care what it uses underneath. Cool man.

Comment: `$out = array_filter($arr, function ($key) { return is_numeric($key); }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);`

Comment: @RobbieAverill thanks and please don't beat me guys :)

Comment: http://lxr.php.net/s?defs=array_filter&project=PHP_5_2 i see a loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you’re using a PHP version >= 5.6, you can use `array_filter`, with the flag that tells it to pass the key to the callback function.

```
$arr = array(
  'key' => 'foo',
  'key2' => 'bar',
   0 => 'num_foo',
   1 => 'num_bar'
);

$new_array = array_filter($arr, function($key) {
  return is_numeric($key);
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

var_dump($new_array);
```

https://3v4l.org/qfar9

---

Edit: As Robbie pointed out, using `is_numeric` is the better choice here. (Previously my example used `is_int`.)

---

Edit 2: Perhaps `is_int` is actually the better choice here. `is_numeric` would return true for values such as `+0123.45e6`, or hexadecimal/binary number notations as well – not sure if that’s desired.

`is_int` would normally return false for a value such as `'1'`. It works here, because we are dealing with arrays – and PHP automatically converts array keys to integer, if they are an “integer string.”

Comment: @RobbieAverill: Yeah, you’re right. I’ll edit that in, thanks.

Comment: @Robbie: Maybe `is_int` is the better choice here after all, see my edit.

Comment: and w/ php >= **v7.4** we'd do even shorter `array_filter($arr, fn($k) => is_int($k), ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);`

Answer (score 1):

you can use `array_filter()` to return the numeric keys

```
// $Your_array is your original array with numeric and string keys
// array_filter() returns an array of the numeric keys
$numerickeys = array_filter(array_keys($Your_array), function($k) {return is_int($k);});

// this is a simple case where the filter function is a plain
// built-in function requiring one argument, it can be passed as a string:
// Really, this is all that's needed:
$numerickeys = array_filter(array_keys($Your_array), 'is_int');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `is_int()` inside a `foreach` loop it's easy enough. Try this:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (is_int($key)) {
        echo "Found integer key with value: $value\n";
    }
}
```

If you desperately want to avoid using a loop, try this:

```
array_walk($arr, function($val, $key) {
    if (is_int($key)) {
        echo "Found integer key with value: $val\n";
    }
});
```

That does, of course, use a loop internally anyway.

Comment: Question says "besides using a loop"

Comment: His comment was "I just prefer inliner", which is a bizarre thing to say. Nevertheless I'll update my answer.

Comment: But internally we have loop written in C (am I right?) and I have big arrays.

Comment: That's a remarkable leap in logic, and definitely premature optimisation. Using array_walk() will call a PHP function once for every item in the array. Is that more efficient than looping directly in PHP? I would be surprised if so. Unless your arrays are genuinely *epic* in scale, give it a try with a loop first and only optimise when you need to.

Comment: Good point. Second reason for using inliner is readability improvement. I thought that there is a better way for this than array_filter etc, because in this case code readability is even worse IMO.

Comment: Loops are a simple, readable, and very boring construct, which is no bad thing for maintainability – there can be times when you want to avoid them, but I suspect this is not one.